# Facebook get access token with manual flow

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am implementing a manual flow for facebook login in our reactjs + meteor app. As of now I have got the code which FB sends in redirect url to my site.

Using this code I was able to make graph api call as shown [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#exchangecode). Then I whitelisted my server IP in the facebook app. Even this works good. I'm able to get an access token by exchanging the code. Below is the code that works here:

```
const accessToken = await HTTP.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/oauth/access_token?client_id=<appID>&redirect_uri=mysite.com/facebook/redirect&client_secret=<appSecret>&code=<code>');
```

But when I enable app secret proof, my graph call returns oauth error code 1 which specifies facebook could not validate app secret. I referred this [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests#appsecret_proof) to check on how to create & pass the app secret proof. I tried generating the app proof by passing code & app secret, one at a time. Below is how I am trying to get an access token:

```
const appSecProof = cryto.createHmac('sha256', <appSecret>).update(<code>).digest('hex');
//<appSecret> is the appSecret from FB App, <code> is the code I get from FB after FB redirects to my site.

const accessToken = await HTTP.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/oauth/access_token?client_id=<appID>&redirect_uri=mysite.com/facebook/redirect&client_secret=<appSecret>&code=<code>&appsecret_proof=<appSecProof>');
```

I am configuring the app right for app secret proof?

The other thought I am getting is if I am doing a manual server side implementation then IP whitelisting alone can take care of security & I don't need to enable app secret proof.

My end goal is to implement a secure the facebook login. I had tried with facebook javascript SDK which works good. But when testing I found it shows the access token in browser network panel's xhr calls. Using this access token I could make a GET call to FB API using postman. So wanted to have all communication from server side.

Thanks.

Comment: you should add the relevant code

Comment: @luschn added the relevant code I am using

Comment: The `code` has nothing to do with the app-secret proof to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe Went through the docs again that FB provides for securing graph calls [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests#appsecret_proof). My understanding here:

1.Graph calls are those which have endpoint graph.facebook.com/somePath
2.Enabling app secret proof requires 'Require App Secret' from Advanced Section in FB App.
3.Endpoint that provides us access token in exchange of `code` is a graph call. See docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#exchangecode).
So using appsecret in this as well. Please advise.

Comment: @CBroe more info - once we enable 'Require App Secret' in FB app, the call to get access token by exchanging code fails.

Comment: Quote from docs, _“The app secret proof is a sha256 hash of your access token, using the app secret as the key.”_ - so it makes no sense that you are trying to calculate it using the `code` value to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe thank you. I understand that which is why I tried anyway using both app secret & code. The documentation does not help on what to do when we want access token for code. Hence asking if am configuring the app correct or app secret proof is not at all needed for manual flow.

Comment: The app secret proof is for API calls that use an access token. The call to exchange the code for a token doesn’t, so this isn’t applicable here in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe I checked the Facebook SDK for PHP which is intended for a Server side implementation. I saw that the SDK does not use `app_secret_proof` for getting access token. See this [code](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/6d1eb5a3861624cd0ff40c67e517de891d78134a/src/Facebook/Authentication/OAuth2Client.php#L159).
This makes me believe that `app_secret_proof` is **not** to be used in a server side implementation.

Comment: Well yeah as I last said ... _"so this isn’t applicable here in the first place."_